# Writing multiple buffers in ping pong mode tiva c

Tags: c, microcontroller, dma, firmware

I'm trying to send multiple buffers each of 1k on EPI interface using uDMA on Tiva.

I can send now two buffers in ping pong mode, but not sure where should I do the swapping between the buffers to support multiple buffers. Here is a snippet of the codes:

So I'm trying to send now two buffers, and after sending I swap Second with third,..etc.
But How do I send more than 3 buffers?

Init of Buffers:

```
    pa = send_data;
    pb  = send_data2;
    pc = send_data3;

void EPIIntHandler(void)
{
    uint32_t intStatus;

    //
    // Handle any EPI error IRQ signals.
    //
    intStatus = EPIIntErrorStatus(EPI0_BASE);
    if(intStatus)
    {
        g_ui32EPIErrors++;
    }
    EPIIntErrorClear(EPI0_BASE, intStatus);
    intStatus = EPIIntStatus(EPI0_BASE, false);

    if(intStatus)
    {
        g_ui32EPIStatus = intStatus;
    }

    //
    // Get any DMA related information. Clear the IRQ.
    //
    intStatus = uDMAIntStatus();
    uDMAIntClear(intStatus);

    if(( uDMAChannelModeGet(UDMA_CHANNEL_TMR1B | UDMA_PRI_SELECT) == UDMA_MODE_STOP) &&
            (pui32BufferStatus[0] == FILLING))
    {
        pui32BufferStatus[0] = FULL;
        pui32BufferStatus[1] = FILLING;

    }
    else if ((uDMAChannelModeGet(UDMA_CHANNEL_TMR1B | UDMA_ALT_SELECT) == UDMA_MODE_STOP) &&
            (pui32BufferStatus[1] == FILLING))
    {

        pui32BufferStatus[0] = FILLING;
        pui32BufferStatus[1] = FULL;
    }

}
```

In Main Loop:

```
 if(pui32BufferStatus[0] == FULL)
        {
            pui32BufferStatus[0] = EMPTY;
            MAP_uDMAChannelTransferSet(UDMA_CH21_EPI0TX | UDMA_PRI_SELECT,
                                       UDMA_MODE_PINGPONG,
                                       (void *)pa,
                                       (void *)g_pusEPIFPGA,
                                       SIZE_TX);
 
 
            MAP_EPIDMATxCount(EPI0_BASE, SIZE_TX);
            SwapBuffers(&pb, &pc);
        }
        //
        // Check if the second buffer is full, if so process data.
        //
        if(pui32BufferStatus[1] == FULL)
        {
            //
            // Indicate the Buffer data as been processed so new data can
            // be stored.
 
            pui32BufferStatus[1] = EMPTY;
            //
            MAP_uDMAChannelTransferSet(UDMA_CH21_EPI0TX | UDMA_ALT_SELECT,
                                       UDMA_MODE_PINGPONG,
                                       (void *)pb,
                                       (void *)g_pusEPIFPGA,
                                       SIZE_TX);
 
 
            SwapBuffers(&pa, &pb);
 
 
 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

implement a circular queue of buffers

step to a new buffer at the 'head' end of the circular queue

consume a buffer at the 'tail' of the circular queue

always check for an empty queue

always check for the queue to be full

Comment: How a circular queue differs from swapping the buffers as I did in the code above ? Would you show a pseudo code ? also I need to transmit as fast as possible so consuming each element from the buffer is a bottelneck